# automated conversion of xlsx to txt file

Tags: conversion, xlsx

I need a way to automate a process where I would get a xlsx file in a folder and have it automatically converted into a tab delminited file (txt) file.What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Can you assume that Office is installed on the machine?

Comment: This looks quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734378/can-you-have-a-excel-macro-to-auto-save-a-copy-as-csv

Comment: Yes office is installed on the machine. Eventually I want to have it done where the folder with files is on a network share.